# クリックした画像を変更したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

クリックした画像をコールバック関数とアニメーションを使って変更させたいです。
以下のコードだとリストの画像をクリックするとアニメーションは適用されているのですが、画像は初期値のsample1が表示され画像の変更ができないです。
どうすればクリックした画像に変更できるでしょうか？

```
<body>
        <main>
            <h1>表示したい画像をクリックしてください</h1>
            <img id="image" src="sample1.jpg" alt="sample1">
            <div id="display">
                <ul id="image_list">
                    <li><a href="sample1.jpg"><img src="sample1.jpg" alt="sample1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="sample2.jpg"><img src="sample2.jpg" alt="sample2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="sample3.jpg"><img src="sample3.jpg" alt="sample3"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="changeImg.js"></script>
        </main>
    </body>
```

```
"use strict"
$(document).ready( () => {
    $("#image_list a").click( evt => {
        let newImage = $("#image_list a").attr("src");
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("#image").animate({opacity: 0, "margin-left": "-100"}, 1000,
        () => {
            $("#image").attr("src", newImage).animate({
            opacity: 1, "margin-left": "+=100"}, 1000
            );
        });
    }) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
        let newImage = $("#image_list a").attr("src");
```

`<a>` に `src` 属性がないから `newImage` が空になっているのでしょう。`href` 属性に変えるか、属性を取る対象を `<a>` の子供の `<img>` にすることが必要です。

また、`$("#image_list a").attr()` と書くとクリックされた `<a>` を無視してマッチする最初の要素から属性を取得します。`evt.target` を使いましょう。